# Error demasiados argumentos bash en un if

Tags: linux, bash, condiciones

Estoy haciendo un script que le pasas por argumento un nombre de usuario y te dice si esta conectado al sistema. Pero me dió este error:

```
ex3.sh: línea 4: [: demasiados argumentos
```

Codigo:

```
#!bin/bash 

r=$(w -uh $1)

if [ $r ];then

echo si

else

echo no

fi
```

Linea 4:

```
if [ $r ];then
```

Si el usuario que le he puesto no esta conectado me da bien pero si pongo uno que si esta conectado me salta el error.Porque me dió ese error? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es un típico caso de: "Te faltaron las comillas" en bash.

En bash las comillas son muy importantes porque evitan el "splitting".

Osea, no es lo mismo poner:

```bash
r="Hola mundo :)"
[ "$r" ]`

# que
r="Hola mundo :)"
[ $r ]
```

En el caso sin comillas, se evalúa como `[ Hola mundo :) ]`, y teniendo más de dos parámetros en el evaluador, además de tokens raros como ":" y ")".

En el caso con comillas, se evalúa como, `[ "Hola mundo :)" ]`, es decir, sólo será un parámetro y la cadena "Hola mundo :)"